# Outlook Add-In with WebView2 component: Whent does it unload?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, webview2

We've developed an Outlook Add-In for an already existing web application. In general, all looks fine: The Add-In pane shows the HTML UI and works so far.

However, the web application has a restriction that only one window each browser can be in use (one session can serve to one browser instance). And it seems, that Outlook Add-In does not unload the browser window/WebView2 component immediately when user decides to close the Add-In pane with the 'x' button.

When the user now tries to open the Add-In again, the web application behind refuses to work, because it has still a connection to the previous browser window (which seems to loiter somewhere in the background) and therefore prevents a proper session end.

Restart of Outlook solves the situation. But this is very bad user experience. Is there a documentation, when WebView2 get's really unloaded for a closed Outlook-Add-In? Or do you know how to force that mechanism?

Comment: How did you find that a browser window still works in the background?

Comment: Do you develop an Outlook web add-in, right?

Comment: > How did you find that a browser window still works in the background? As written in the question: The server continues session and this is due the same session cookie , which means, the browser component somehow survived ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WebView2 control, I assume you mean a COM addin that explicitly creates a task pane.

`CustomTaskPane` object fires [VisibleStateChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customtaskpane.visiblestatechange) event when the task pane is closed. You can also trap `Inspector.Close` event if the task pane is used in an Inspector.

Comment: That could make sense for VSTO/COM add-ins. Office web add-ins don't provide anything like that.

Comment: Eugene is right, question is about Office web-add-in, not COM-Add-In